# Running Chrome From Python Subprocess Won't Allow Use of Specified User-Data-Dir

Tags: python, google-chrome, subprocess

I am trying to open chrome through a python script using subprocess but it is not allowing me to use a specified user data directory, and thus defaults to my default user data directory. I get a pop up error reading "Google chrome cannot read and write to its data directory".

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run([
        'chrome.exe',
        '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
        '--user-data-dir="C:\\selenum\\ChromeProfile"'
        ])
```

I am using Windows 10. If I open chrome with git-bash with command...

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\ChromeProfile"
```

...then it works just fine. I'm thinking that this might be a permissions thing when running chrome out of a python script, but not certain.